# Optimizing determining whether a subset of a string can be rearranged to form another string

Tags: javascript, algorithm

Complete the function `scramble(str1, str2)` that returns true if a portion of `str1` characters can be rearranged to match `str2`, otherwise returns false.

Notes:

- Only lower case letters will be used (a-z). No punctuation or digits will be included.
- Performance needs to be considered
- Input strings `s1` and `s2` are null terminated.

Examples

```
'rkqodlw', 'world' ==> True
'katas', 'steak' ==> False
```

My Code:

```
function scramble(str1, str2) {
  let str = '';

  for (i = 0; i < str2.length; i++) {
    if (str1.includes(str2[i])) {
      str1 = str1.replace(str2[i], '')
      str += str2[i]
    }
    if (str === str2) return true
  }
  return false
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If the strings are so unreasonably huge that runtime really is an issue, you can group one of the strings into an object first, so that the overall complexity is `O(n)` instead of `O(n ^ 2)`:

```js
function scramble(str1, str2) {
  const grouped = {};
  for (const char of str1) {
    grouped[char] = (grouped[char] || 0) + 1;
  }
  for (const char of str2) {
    if (!grouped[char]) return false;
    grouped[char]--;
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(scramble('rkqodlw', 'world'));
console.log(scramble('katas', 'steak'));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in linear time by making a frequency counter for each word. If, for every unique character in `str2`, you find that its count of letters is `<=` the count for that character in `str1`, then return true because `str1` has some subset of characters that could form `str2`.

Code:

```js
const frequencyCount = s => [...s].reduce((a, e) => {
  a[e] = ++a[e] || 1;
  return a;
}, {});
  
const scramble = (a, b) => {
  const aFreq = frequencyCount(a);  
  return Object.entries(frequencyCount(b)).every(([e, count]) =>
    count <= aFreq[e] 
  );
};

console.log(scramble("rkqodlw", "world"));
console.log(scramble("katas", "steak"));
```